# Creating instance of eloquent with multiple relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

I have 3 models:
Plugin, Review and User.

The User is the parent of Plugin. At a one-to-many relationship I can create a plugin asociated with the user easily:

```
$user->plugins()->create([...options...]);
```

But now my problem is: A Review is the child of both User and Plugin. How to create a review with the User and the Plugin without setting one ID manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that a Review belongsTo a User and a Plugin, you can use the `associate()` method of the relationship to set the foreign keys. Note, this method only sets the proper attribute on the object; you still have to `save()` the object to update the database.

Here is an example:

```
$plugin = $user->plugins()->create([...plugin options...]);

// instantiate a new review instance
$review = new \App\Review([...review options...]);

// set the user association
$review->user()->associate($user);

// set the plugin association
$review->plugin()->associate($plugin);

// save the entire record to the database
$review->save();
```

Comment: Works, thanks! That was exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Is it possible to associate several models on create? I have 2 relations with foreigns, both of them aren't nullable and I got an error if I try to create a model with associate without providing another related record id.